# SAS EG System.AccessViolationException SAS.CIODSFileEvents_EventProvider.remove_FileClose(SAS.CIODSFileEvents_FileCloseEventHandler)

Tags: sas

We have two Windows 7 client PCs with SAS EG 7.10. and a .Net program that runs the SAS programs on a separate SAS server running SAS 9.4. We recently started getting this error on one of the client PCs when a SAS program completes...

> System.AccessViolationException at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IConnectionPoint.Unadvise(Int32)
>   at
>   SAS.CIODSFileEvents_EventProvider.remove_FileClose(SAS.CIODSFileEvents_FileCloseEventHandler)
>   at
>   SAS.CIODSFileEvents_Event.remove_FileClose(SAS.CIODSFileEvents_FileCloseEventHandler)
>   at SAS.EC.Directory.Model.SASWorkspace.Dispose(Boolean) at
>   SAS.EC.Directory.Model.Server.Dispose(Boolean) at
>   SAS.EC.Directory.Model.Root.Dispose(Boolean) at
>   SAS.EC.Directory.Model.Broker.Dispose(Boolean) at
>   SAS.EC.Directory.DirectoryService.Dispose(Boolean) at
>   SAS.EC.Session.LocalSession.Cleanup() at
>   SAS.EG.Scripting.Application.Dispose(Boolean) at
>   SAS.EG.Scripting.Application.Finalize()

The same SAS program runs fine from the other client PC. The only thing that may have changed is that the failing Windows 7 PC may have been patched and I noticed the .Net version is now 4.6 whereas I think it was 4.5.1 before as it is on the other client PC.

I found an article saying that SAS EG prior to v7.13 requires .Net 4.5.1 whereas SAS EG 7.13 and later requires .Net 4.6.

We also get the same error on a new Windows 10 client PC we are setting up that has .Net 4.8 and we have installed SAS EG 7.15 which we thought would be more compatible with Windows 10.

Can anyone explain why we get this error and whether there is anything we can do in a SAS program to fix it or whether this is due to incompatibilities between SAS  versions and if so what SAS EG versions can we use on Windows 10 to connect to a SAS Server running SAS 9.4 ?

Thanks